# server.connection-timeout not working or another way around?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, timeout

I am using Spring boot version 2.1.7.RELEASE

Requirement: I need to serve a request coming on my service on any end point in finite time let say 3 seconds, and if a requests takes more than that then I want to terminate the request. I am using In Built tomcat which is there in spring boot maven project.

need a way that resolves the above requirement.

I have tried using **server.connection-timeout**, **server.tomcat.connection-timeout** set values in bootstrap.properties which is not working,

**How I am testing :** I have created a controller having a simple get Api method and added thread.sleep in it to increase the api processing time, and hitting the api from postman while making application UP on intellij itself.

Comment: try placing them on application.properties. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bootstrap-properties

Comment: @LMC both application.properties and bootstrap.properties file used to set the configurations, all thought as suggested by you I have tried putting the configs in application.properties as well, sadly it is not work either.

Comment: Giving it a second thought you need a request timeout not a connection timeout. The latter is the time it takes to stablish a connection not to complete the request. It's probably easier to set a request timeout client side like browsers do. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-timeout

Comment: @LMC I got your point but why I need this at first place is, let say I have time out value of 1 second on client side and in actual the request is taking 6 seconds to get completed some times so for 5 seconds the request is holding some resource of my server, which if - that request would have been terminated in 2 seconds then my resource would have been available to serve more requests and faster. So I need a way - in which if the incoming request is taking more than 2 seconds to server I want it to be terminated.

Comment: Note: I am using straightforward methods at controller level which returns ResponseEntity and not Callable<String>.

Comment: That's a different problem, client has nothing to do. Take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stop-execution-after-certain-time. BTW, do you know why those methods take more than x seconds?

Comment: I am also dependent on other services so on the fly instantly you never know what can go wrong.

Comment: @LMC so as per the document provided by you, if we see from a broad point of view we do not have any config level implementation by spring boot or embedded tomcat yet, to achieve what we needed here. The solution mentioned in doc is quite understandable that to achieve this we should run every request in separate thread which we can terminate on interruption or use Future to time it out. But creating separate thread for every request is not reliable solution I can go with.